# nginx GEOIP behind cloudflare proxy showing wrong country (not of end user, but if proxy)

Tags: nginx, php, cloudflare, geoip

I am using Cloudflare and nginx geoip directives:

```
geoip_country /usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat;
geoip_city /usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat;
```

They are picking the IP up OK (as `pipaddress` since the request is marked as forwarded in the header), but is showing the country as SG (the cloudflare proxy location).

Is there anyway if the header `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` is set, to get the coutnry of the end user?

```
<?php
    if (getenv(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR))
    {
        $pipaddress = getenv(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR);
        $ipaddress = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR);
        echo "Your IP address is : ".$pipaddress. " (via proxy $ipaddress) " ;
    }
    else
    {
        $ipaddress = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR);
        echo "Your IP address is : $ipaddress";
    }

    $country = getenv(GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME);
    $country_code = getenv(GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE);
    echo "<br/>Your country : $country ( $country_code ) ";
?>
```

And `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params` are below:

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $request_filename;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# Set php-fpm geoip variables
fastcgi_param GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE $geoip_country_code;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE3 $geoip_country_code3;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME $geoip_country_name;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_CITY_COUNTRY_CODE $geoip_city_country_code;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_CITY_COUNTRY_CODE3 $geoip_city_country_code3;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_CITY_COUNTRY_NAME $geoip_city_country_name;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_REGION $geoip_region;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_CITY $geoip_city;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_POSTAL_CODE $geoip_postal_code;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_CITY_CONTINENT_CODE $geoip_city_continent_code;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_LATITUDE $geoip_latitude;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_LONGITUDE $geoip_longitude;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your nginx server cannot determine the real IP of the request to pass to PHP. The workaround is to use Nginx's Real IP module.

Check this out https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170706-How-do-I-restore-original-visitor-IP-with-Nginx-

Just add that code snippet from the link to your config file and restart nginx.

Answer (score 3):

Extension for the answer by @the_nuts. I threw together a small script which automatically generates `geoip_proxy` instructions list based on the lists on cloudflare page:

```
#!/bin/sh
# /etc/nginx/geoip_update.sh
# Update GeoIP proxy list to the current list of cloudflare IP addresses

outfile=$(dirname "$0")/geoip_cloudflare.conf

echo "# Auto-generated by $0" > "$outfile"
(
    curl https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v4
    curl https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v6
) | while read ip; do
    echo "geoip_proxy $ip;"
done > "$outfile"
echo List updated.
```

Usage: launch this script once and it will generate `/etc/nginx/geoip_cloudflare.conf` file. Then add the following to your `http` block:

```
include /etc/nginx/geoip_cloudflare.conf;
```

Optionally, add the script to cron to update IP lists regularly. Not sure how often do they change though.

Caution: the script is not very optimized, during updates the config/include file will be empty for short time. If nginx is restarted at exactly that time then geoip_proxy instructions won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is to set the CloudFlare IP ranges as trusted proxies, using the [geoip_proxy](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geoip_module.html) directive. No additional modules are required.

As of today, it results in the following:

```
geoip_proxy 103.21.244.0/22;
geoip_proxy 103.22.200.0/22;
geoip_proxy 103.31.4.0/22;
geoip_proxy 104.16.0.0/12;
geoip_proxy 108.162.192.0/18;
geoip_proxy 131.0.72.0/22;
geoip_proxy 141.101.64.0/18;
geoip_proxy 162.158.0.0/15;
geoip_proxy 172.64.0.0/13;
geoip_proxy 173.245.48.0/20;
geoip_proxy 188.114.96.0/20;
geoip_proxy 190.93.240.0/20;
geoip_proxy 197.234.240.0/22;
geoip_proxy 198.41.128.0/17;
geoip_proxy 2400:cb00::/32;
geoip_proxy 2405:b500::/32;
geoip_proxy 2606:4700::/32;
geoip_proxy 2803:f800::/32;
geoip_proxy 2c0f:f248::/32;
geoip_proxy 2a06:98c0::/29;
```

You can find the updated list of CloudFlare IPs here: https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/

Comment: I got `nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "set_geoip_proxy" in`

Comment: @SalemF it's not `set_geoip_proxy`, it's just `geoip_proxy`. It requires the geoip2 nginx module, which is available in the `nginx-full` or `nginx-extras` flavor, on ubuntu/debian (if you have only `nginx-core` or `nginx-light`, you need to install it with `apt install nginx-full`)